# How can i insert data into a column of a table (out of 2 tables) such that user id matches in both of them?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert data into a column of a table (out of 2 tables) such that user id matches in both of them?  table 1 is `users` and table 2 is `comments`

Here is the query I am using:

```
$query='INSERT INTO comments VALUES('','','$comment','','') WHERE users.id=comments.id';
```

but it says an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '','' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\my\lecture1.php on line 263

where line 263 is the query

Comment: That's a PHP error.  Check the syntax on your line.  HINT: How are you adding `$comment` to the string?

Comment: P.S. As [@sh-ado-w](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26107791/206403) pointed out, using a `WHERE` in an `INSERT` query makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: can you please elaborate it , i am not able to get your point.

Comment: Make a cross table, combining Comments, UserId and the ArticleId where the comments are in in order to store that. Better that way then trying to insert something in an already excisting table with comments field in it

Comment: @bhavdeepsingh: Which point are you asking me about?  Your error is a PHP error because your syntax is wrong.  I was just also pointing out that `INSERT INTO comments VALUES () WHERE ...` makes no sense.  You can't use `INSERT` and `WHERE`.

Comment: This point :" How are you adding $comment to the string? "

Comment: @bhavdeepsingh: Look at the line.  Check the PHP syntax.  You are not correctly concatenating `$comment` into `$query`.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` can only include new records. To modify the value of a field in an existing record, use `UPDATE`.

For instance:

```
UPDATE comments SET comment = 'Blah, blah blah.' WHERE id = 1;
```

You can cross tables while using `UPDATE`, however I don't see any reason to do that in this case.

You can also use `INCLUDE` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` trigger to create the record if it doesn't exist or update an existing one with the same query. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` trigger is triggered when the insertion of the new record is impossible because the `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` specified is already present in the table. Example:

```
INSERT INTO comments (id, comment) VALUES (1, 'Comment') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comment = 'Comment';
```